# Not directing to div id target when scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, polymer

Have problems with firefox 33.1 my scroll to div is not directing to my target div id im using polymer core-scaffold as my navigation but **its working fine using chrome**

and i don't have any errors on my console

**here's my script**

```
<script>

    var scaffold = document.getElementById('scaffold');
    var menu = document.getElementById('menu');

    menu.addEventListener('core-select', function(e) {
      if (e.detail.isSelected) {
        scrollToSection(e.detail.item.getAttribute('name'));
      }
    });

    function scrollToSection(id) {
      var section = document.getElementById(id);
      if (section) {
        scaffold.$.headerPanel.scroller.scrollTop = section.offsetTop;
      }
    }

  </script>
```

**here's my navigation code**

```
<core-scaffold id="scaffold" responsiveWidth="640px">
<core-header-panel navigation flex mode="seamed">
<core-toolbar>Navigation</core-toolbar>
<core-menu id="menu">
<core-item name="drawerPanel" icon="home" label="Home"><a href="#"></a></core-item>
<core-item name="about" icon="account-circle" label="Who"></core-item>
<core-item name="works" icon="work" label="Works"></core-item>
<core-item name="skills-cont" icon="gesture" label="Skills" name="skills"></core-item>
<core-item name="contacts-cont" icon="settings-phone" label="Contacts"></core-item>
<core-item name="cart" icon="shopping-cart" label="D Shop"><a href="#" target="_blank"></a></core-item>
<core-item name="v8" icon="link" label="v8"><a href="" target="_blank"></a></core-item>
<core-item name="v7" icon="link" label="v7"><a href="" target="_blank"></a></core-item>
<core-item name="v6" icon="link" label="v6"><a href="" target="_blank"></a></core-item>
</core-menu>


<div id="about">
<about-koh></about-koh>
</div>


<div id="works">
<works></works>
</div>

....
```

is it possible to change the offsetTop depends on browser like if **in firefox** i want it to **offsetTop -75** then **in chrome** it will be **offsetTop -10** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok found out that the reason was my jquery script i had this script and it has a duplicate script with different class so to fix it i remove the duplicate script.

**my old script reason i got problem**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var posts = jQuery('.ab-effect').children();

    function animateCircle() {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            jQuery(posts[i]).addClass('visible animated fadeInUp');
        } else {
            jQuery(posts[i]).addClass('visible animated fadeInDown');
        }
        i++;
        if (i <= posts.length) {
            startAnimation();
        }
    }

    function startAnimation() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            animateCircle();}, 1000);
    }

    posts.addClass('hidden');
    animateCircle(posts);
});

jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var posts = jQuery('.sk-effect').children();

    function animateCircle() {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            jQuery(posts[i]).addClass('visible animated fadeInUp');
        } else {
            jQuery(posts[i]).addClass('visible animated fadeInDown');
        }
        i++;
        if (i <= posts.length) {
            startAnimation();
        }
    }

    function startAnimation() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            animateCircle();}, 1000);
    }

    posts.addClass('hidden');
    animateCircle(posts);
});
```

**my new script that fix my problem - i just remove the duplicate script**

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 0;
    var posts = jQuery('.ab-effect').children();

    function animateCircle() {
        if (i % 2 === 0) {
            jQuery(posts[i]).addClass('visible animated fadeInUp');
        } else {
            jQuery(posts[i]).addClass('visible animated fadeInDown');
        }
        i++;
        if (i <= posts.length) {
            startAnimation();
        }
    }

    function startAnimation() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            animateCircle();}, 1000);
    }

    posts.addClass('hidden');
    animateCircle(posts);
});
```